# How can I exit Microsoft GW-BASIC, IBM BASICA, or other similar old dialects of BASIC?

Tags: exit, basic, gw-basic

[Microsoft BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_BASIC), [GW-BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GW-BASIC) and [BASICA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASICA) all use a prompt that looks like this:

[image]

I can't figure out how to exit any of these. Typing `END` does not exit them. `EXIT`, `QUIT`, `Q`, <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, and everything else that I can think of also does not work.

I'm sure there's a way to do this. I can't imagine everyone who used BASICA on DOS had to restart their machine every single time they wanted to exit the development environment.

So, how do I exit from the old BASIC editor prompt?

Comment: BASICA is the new vim?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

GWBASIC and its clones (e.g., IBM's BASIC and BASICA) exited to the DOS prompt with the command `system`.

Although redirection was possible even in early versions of MS-DOS/PC-DOS, the BASIC interpreter bypassed using the standard input and output streams, and had its own <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Break</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> handler, so neither of those keystrokes would terminate the interpreter.
The `shell` command started a fresh copy of the system command interpreter (usually COMMAND.COM), or executed a system command and then returned to BASIC, but did not remove the interpreter from memory.

Comment: @PTBW - I believe that MBASIC was a GW-BASIC clone, or a cut-down version of it; I never used CP/M, however, so my knowledge of it is 'academic' or 'anecdotal'.

Comment: Oh that's right, `system`. An old, retired neuron just woke up.

Answer (score 7):

Type "system" and hit enter to exit GW-BASIC in DOS.

Type "shell" and hit enter to go to DOS but still have GW-BASIC in memory. Type "exit" while in DOS to return to GW-BASIC.

Comment: Thanks. This is the only thing that worked if you are also running a dos emulator like dosbox.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for those command line editors `Ctl-Z` would do the trick since it sends the EOF character and thus signal terminating input.

If that doesn't do it, try typing `system`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual linked by paulsm4](https://web-beta.archive.org/web/20160509151155/http://www.gw-basic.com:80/gw-man.pdf), CTRL-BREAK *while output is being redirected* will exit BASIC.  It also says the SHELL command returns to the MS-DOS command shell.  (On the original IBM PC, the BASIC was in ROM, and therefore always resident in memory.)